# Angular Modular File Structure

Tags: javascript, angularjs

This post was based on [this](http://cliffmeyers.com/blog/2013/4/21/code-organization-angularjs-javascript).

My intention is to separate components on a file basis. For example, I want a specific controller to have it's own file (Same goes with services, filters and directives). Of course, files will be group together based on the module they will fall into. Here's an overview of what I currently have:

Directory

```
User/
    User/UserModule.js
    User/UserDirective.js
    User/UserService.js
    User/UserFilter.js
    User/UserController.js
```

UserModules.js

```
UserModule = angular.module('UserModule', []);

UserModule.controller('userCtrl', ['$scope', 'UserService', UserCtrl])

    .factory('userService', function() {
        return new UserService();
    })  

    .filter('userFilter', UserFilter)

    .directive('userDirective', UserDirective);
```

UserController.js

```
UserCtrl = function($scope, UserService) {
    // ...
};
```

UserDirective.js

```
UserDirective = function() {
    return {
        // ...
    }
};
```

UserService.js

```
UserService = function() {
    // ...
};
```

UserFilter.js

```
UserFilter = function() {
    return function() {
        // ...
    }
};
```

Then I'll just push the user module to the app module.

```
app.requires.push('UserModule');
```

My concern lies on the registration of the concepts (Such as controllers, services...) to the module. I was wondering if this is the best way to go and if it's correct. Also possible issues on the `parameters` and the external js file.

Consider this part:

```
.controller('userCtrl', ['$scope', 'UserService', UserCtrl])
```

The `UserCtrl` above refers to a function defined in a separate file. Will I be able to pass the `$scope` and `UserService` dependency as parameters to the `UserCtrl`?

```
UserCtrl = function($scope, UserService) { // Pass parameters (UserController.js)
```

What's the correct way of doing this in terms of Services, Filters and Directives?

Finally, how can I improve the code?

I'm also using Meteor btw.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not need to declare global variables `UserModule, UserDirective, UserService`. You just need to declare/register them as below. Angular will take care of injecting dependencies.

UserModule.js

```
angular.module('UserModule', []);
```

UserDirective.js

```
angular.module('UserModule').directive('userDirective', function() {
   return {
      // ...
   }
});
```

UserService.js

```
angular.module('UserModule').service('UserService', function() {

});
```

UserController.js

```
angular.module('UserModule').controller('UserController', ['$scope', 'UserService', function($scope, UserService){
}])
```

Comment: Great! With this approach, is the loading order of the js files have any effect?

Comment: You need to load UserModule.js first. The controllers, directives and services can be loaded any order.